# Remove elements from a int array that have value 0 and save the deleted index

Tags: python, arrays

I've an array containing some 0's and I want to remove them from the array. I also want to save the position of those 0, on another array called `deleted_array_index`

```
array = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 5, 6, 0]
```

to:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6]
```

And also save the deletex index  (the position where 0's were) on another array, in this case:

```
deleted_index_array = [2, 3, 5, 9]
```

For deleting the 0's I tried: `print [ x for x in array if '0']` but it's not working.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 5, 6, 0]
```

now.... "enumerate(array)" will return the value and index for every item in the array.

```
deleted_index_array = [i for i, x in enumerate(array) if x == 0]
```

now filter the array

```
array = [i for i in array if i != 0]
```

Comment: the `deleted_index_array` shows the desired answer, but `array` (the last line you posted) removes me the entire array and prints me an empty array.

Comment: It's working now, he wrote x instead of i in the second list comp.

Comment: that was a typo. should be i, instead of x.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, although your list comprehension is a little wrong. Try:

```
print [ x if x != '0' for x in array]
```

A nicer way would be:

```
deleted_index_array = [x if array[x] == '0' for x in len(array)]
for i in deleted_index_array:
  array.remove(array[i])
```